# VSTO Outlook: Embed an WPF user control within a form region

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, customtaskpane

Currently I have an WPF user control embedded within an Outlook custom task pane. The problem with the task pane is that you cannot remove the title bar so I was thinking about using a form region instead and reusing the existing WPF user control I already have. So, is it possible to embed an WPF user control within a form region? If so how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add WPF controls directly to UI elements in Office solutions. Instead, add a User Control (WPF) item to your project, and use it as the design surface for WPF controls. Then, add the WPF user control to a UI element in your project. Visual Studio automatically creates an [ElementHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost) object that hosts the WPF user control on the UI element. Or just add the `ElementHost` control to the user control and then configure it to host your WPF control.

Read more about that in the [Use WPF controls in Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/using-wpf-controls-in-office-solutions?view=vs-2022) article.